# Delete row from logged in user details using pdo php

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am trying to create a delete option or button where the user can enter the id and delete their appointment, BUT currently if they enter any id it will delete that to, i want to restrict the user so that they can only delete their appointments and not other users appointments.  Any help would be great. Here is what i currently have:

```
   <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  
    ?></td>
   <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['month'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  
   ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['hour'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    ?></td>
   <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['minute'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['illness'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    ?></td>
    <td><a href="delete_memberapp.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
   delete </a></td>
    </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </table><br />
```

Here is the form

```
     <form action="delete.php" method="post">

      Enter Booking reference to delete appointment : <input type="text" 
      name="id" required><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete appointment">

    </form>
```

Here is the delete file:

```
      if(isset($_POST['delete']))
     {
     try {
    $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=doctor","root","");
   } catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
    }


     $id = $_POST['id'];



    $pdoQuery = "DELETE FROM `booking` WHERE `id` = :id";

    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

      $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":id"=>$id));

      if($pdoExec)
       {
       echo 'Data Deleted';
       }else
       {
    echo 'ERROR Data Not Deleted';
      }

    }
```

table structure:

```
   --
   -- Table structure for table `booking`
          --

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booking` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `hour` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `minute` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `illness` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `call_patient` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=80 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this what you wrote you can delete any row with any id. To secure that user can delete only his appointment you need to add into your query:

```
$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$pdoQuery = "DELETE FROM `booking` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `username`= '$username' ";
```

I just assumed names of vars and table rows but in general it needs to be done like this

Edit:

Try maybe this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

$pdoQuery = "DELETE FROM `booking` WHERE `id` = :id AND `username`= :username";

$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":id"=>$id,":username"=>$username));
```

Comment: @asaf Can you extract session user id? What is the name of that  var? Do you have in your booking table column for user id?

Comment: This is my display query which displays the appointmens for the logged in users:   
             $query = "
             SELECT
     id,
            date,
            month,
            hour,
            minute,
            illness
         FROM booking WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']     ['username']."'
    ";

Comment: It is still deleting any id that is inputted.

Comment: $username = $_SESSION['user']['username']; may be needs . to separate if its array. Not sure though.

Comment: If this is your query to select users bookings `$query = " SELECT id, date, month, hour, minute, illness FROM booking WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user'] ['username']."'` then this user will be able to delete any of his bookings with query `$pdoQuery = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE id = '$id' AND username= '$username' ";` But others users when they are logged in will not be able to delete his bookings. Am i right @asaf?

Comment: This query is to display users appointments when they are logged in. The delete query is the one that is not working the current query i have for delete is deleting any id and not the logged in users appointments, it will delete them or any id that is inputted.

Comment: Okay lets sumerize, this query: `$pdoQuery = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE id = '$id' AND username= '$username' ";` can not delete any row by simply changing id. It will delete only for example where username is "John" okay. But if you want to delete row with some other id where username is "Peter" simply query will not delete this row. Please check Value of $_SESSION['user']['username'] and also check in table in column username do you have different usernames.

Comment: Is there not a way where i can restrict the user to only choose his booking ids from a drop down or select option?

Comment: if i log in with different username it displays his appointments so the display query is working fine. Value of  $_SESSION['user']['username'] not sure on this

Comment: As much as i understand every user when he is logged in, should be able to delete any of his appointments but not other users appointments. This we do with  WHERE id = '$id' AND username= '$username' so only if username is matching with the one in db and id also then it will be deleted. If username is not matching with the one from db it will not delete. I would like to help but maybe i will need more info on this, because maybe there somewhere else a problem. @asaf

Comment: no actually iv run further tests it is NOT deleting other users appointments but only logged in user appointments so the delete query is working fine. Your query was right, the only reason i kept on saying it is because when you hit delete button it says deleted but in database record is still there

Comment: its just the error message kept coming as data deleted but was not deleting on actual database

Comment: Not sure why the second error message was not echoing data not deleted

Comment: Okay wait so you wanna say that he is not deleting other users appointments just you are not getting error? @asaf

Comment: Yes if i i try to delete other users appointments they are not deleting but after hitting delete button error message comes up as data deleted

Comment: but does it delete another users appointment. Or query works just you echoing error? or its still possible to delete someone else appointment? alse can you echo $pdoExec value and see it  @asaf

Comment: echo $pdoExec gives echo of 1.for both user and non user appointments.....no 100% its not deleting other users appointments only his own. its just echo error for some reason.

Comment: great that means that we fixed security thing now we have problem with value of $pdoExec. Can you echo it and see what is value when you delete allowed appointment and what is value of it when you try to delete unallowed users appointment

Comment: @asaf do you have any progress?

Comment: it echo 1 even if it not delete row? @asaf

Comment: normaly $pdoExec should return false if it did not return any row hmmm strange @asaf

Comment: i will just remove the error message on redirect to appointments after delete

Comment: okay, just its really strange why not return false if not delete any row. But good that you fix the main issue

Comment: yeah much appreciated was stuck on it for few hours. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

If your `booking` table has a field with `user_id`, you should add `user_id` to `where`:

```
$pdoQuery = "DELETE FROM `booking` WHERE `id` = :id AND user_id = %USERID%";
```

If your `booking` table doesn't have such field - you **must** add it, there's no other option. Unless you have some other table, which stores bookings of a certain user.

Comment: getting a bit confused here, booking table has a field called id which is primary and auto increment, if i add additional field as you mentioned does this need to be auto increment and primary?

Comment: No. This field contains user_id, id of user who made a booking. Please post `booking` table structure to your question.

Comment: Apologies not sure how to post table structure ok let me have a try

Comment: i have posted table structure if that helps